# Making DIVs that contain SWF Objects draggable in IE9 with jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-draggable

Just as the title says, I have a div that contains a SWF object (created by Uploadify) and I want it to be draggable, but IE9 seems to be refusing to allow me to do that. When the SWF Object has been initialized you will see the text "SELECT FILES" and you will be unable to drag the box around in IE9. It works in FF and Chrome. Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/axzdR/7/

The console is returning this error message:
SCRIPT5007: Object expected jquery.min.js, line 2 character 22741
(error message courtesy of Wirey)

Comment: It's working for me in IE9 Version 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: You can drag the box around? I'm looking at it right now in the exact same version of IE9 (64-bit) and clicking and dragging is doing nothing.

Comment: Yup I can drag it around just like in Chrome

Comment: strange, it worked for me too but when i refreshed the page it stopped working

Comment: If you click on "SELECT FILES" does it open up an explorer window for you?

Comment: Nope.. not in chrome.  I actually don't see `Select Files` in IE9

Comment: it did the first time but after when i refreshed the page it stopped working

Comment: Wirey: "Select Files" is the SWF object. It's working in your IE9 because the SWF object isn't even being created. Maybe your browser is blocking flash or you're in the No-Addons mode of IE9

Comment: That makes sense. Yeah my SWF was disabled.  I'm getting a `SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 22741` in the console

Comment: I'm using the non-min jquery now and here's the new error.  `SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'uploadify': object is null or undefined`

Comment: You have an extra comma in here `'uploader' : 'http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.php',` <-----  not sure if it's your problem but IE definitely breaks on those

Comment: Good catch Wirey, but unfortunately it still isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading jQuery before your other libraries.  Here's a fiddle of it working in IE9 now.

http://jsfiddle.net/axzdR/9/

Comment: @Colin  Last resort would be to force IE8 Standards using this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >`  It also seems to work for me.  Just put it above your link/script tags  http://jsfiddle.net/axzdR/17/